# How to do a "full" union with the R package sf

Tags: r, r-sf

I try to do a union between three polygons using `sf::st_union`. In the figure below showing the result from ArcGIS "Overlay, Union, All" I wish to obtain a similar result as the five different polygons in 'OUTPUT' by using the sf package in R.

[image]

```
library(sf)
a1 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0, 10), c(45, 10), c(45, 90), c(0, 90), c(0, 10))))
a2 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(45, 10), c(90,10), c(90, 90), c(45, 90), c(45, 10))))
b <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(15, 5), c(75, 5), c(75, 50), c(15, 50), c(15, 5))))
a <- st_sf(c(st_sfc(a1), st_sfc(a2)))
b <- st_sf(st_sfc(b))
a$station <- c(1, 2)
b$type <- "A"
ab_union <- st_union(a, b)
```

In this simple example the resulting sf object 'ab_union' will only contain two polygons, not the expected five. Can I get the wanted result with five objects as in the figure above by using functions in the `sf` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a function that make everything in one step, but this is a way to resolve your problem:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(tidyverse)

a1 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0, 10), c(45, 10), c(45, 90), c(0, 90), c(0, 10))))
a2 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(45, 10), c(90,10), c(90, 90), c(45, 90), c(45, 10))))
b1 <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(15, 5), c(75, 5), c(75, 50), c(15, 50), c(15, 5))))

a <- st_sf(station=c(1, 2), geometry=st_sfc(a1, a2))
b <- st_sf(type="A",   geometry=st_sfc(b1))

st_agr(a) = "constant" #to avoid warnings, but see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/406
st_agr(b) = "constant"

#Operations
plot(st_geometry(st_union(a,b)))

op1 <- st_difference(a,st_union(b)) #notice the use of st_union()
plot(st_geometry(op1), border="red", add=TRUE)

op2 <- st_difference(b, st_union(a)) #notice the order of b and a and st_union()
plot(st_geometry(op2), border="green", add=TRUE)

op3 <- st_intersection(b, a) #notice the order of b and a
plot(st_geometry(op3), border="blue", add=TRUE)

union <- rbind(op1, op2, op3) #Error because op1 (op2) doesn't have the column "type" ("station")
#> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)): names do not match previous names

op11 <- dplyr::mutate(op1, type=NA)
op22 <- dplyr::mutate(op2, station=NA)

union <- rbind(op11, op22, op3)
(as.data.frame(union)) #The row names must be ordered.
#>     station type                       geometry
#> 1         1 <NA> POLYGON ((15 10, 0 10, 0 90...
#> 2         2 <NA> POLYGON ((45 50, 45 90, 90 ...
#> 3        NA    A POLYGON ((75 10, 75 5, 15 5...
#> 11        1    A POLYGON ((15 10, 15 50, 45 ...
#> 1.1       2    A POLYGON ((45 50, 75 50, 75 ...
plot(union)


#Other approach for avoid create the new columns would be:

union2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(op1, op2, op3) #But see discusion here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/49
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Vectorizing 'sfc_POLYGON' elements may not
#> preserve their attributes

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Vectorizing 'sfc_POLYGON' elements may not
#> preserve their attributes

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Vectorizing 'sfc_POLYGON' elements may not
#> preserve their attributes
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The discussions I refer:
https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/406

https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/49

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution! For op3 I don't see the need for a specific order of a or b, since you only keep the intersecting areas of both. I am surprised that I cannot find a built in solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I also needed such a function, so here's my version for arbitrary sf objects, avoiding to explicitly add missing columns. It needs the 'plyr' library in addition (function rbind.fill):

```
my_union <- function(a,b) {
   #
   # function doing a real GIS union operation such as in QGIS or ArcGIS
   #
   # a - the first sf
   # b - the second sf
   #
   st_agr(a) = "constant"
   st_agr(b) = "constant"
   op1 <- st_difference(a,st_union(b))
   op2 <- st_difference(b, st_union(a))
   op3 <- st_intersection(b, a)
   union <- rbind.fill(op1, op2, op3)
   return(st_as_sf(union))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. However I cannot get this to work. After running the code I try to view the resulting dataframe but gets "Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 2) : z error - expecting three columns". I use versions sf 1.0-2, plyr 1.8.6, R 4.1.1.

Comment: I think this is because at least some of your input data has a z value in the coordinates. I only used this on XY data until now.

Comment: No z values in coordinates. I used my test data from the initial post. Here the geometry was not named correctly. When using the same testdata created with the code from CamiloEr everything worked nicely.