# Union of Two sf Objects

Tags: r, union, r-sf

I want to perform what I would call a union on 2 sf objects.
I have the following code:

```
east.west.sf   <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(1,2,2,1,1),c(0,0,2,2,0)))),
                     st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,2,2,0)))))
east.west.df   <- data.frame(var1=c("east", "west"), var2=c(1,2))
east.west      <- st_sf(east.west.df, geom=east.west.sf)

north.south.sf <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,2,2,0,0),c(1,1,2,2,1)))),
                     st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,2,2,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0)))))
north.south.df <- data.frame(var3=c("north", "south"), var4=c(FALSE, TRUE))
north.south    <- st_sf(north.south.df, geom=north.south.sf)

map.overlay    <- st_union(east.west, north.south)                            
st_area(map.overlay)
```

I was expecting all four areas to be 1 unit.  Why are they 3 units?
An analogous union() operation with sp objects gives me what I expect.
How can I get four features of 1 unit each with my two initial sf objects?

Comment: A similar question has been asked on 2019-Feb-15.  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54710574/how-to-do-a-full-union-with-the-r-package-sf>

Comment: st_intersection() is what I needed.

Comment: Also this could be achieved by `st_join()`.